# Android Test File Permission Denied

Tags: android, android-testing

I have a test that tries to write a file from assets to the files directory. But running the test fails with

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/de.*package*/files/model.zip 
(Permission denied)
```

The exception occurs in line

```
val fos = FileOutputStream(filePath);
```

filePath has the correct path. Running this code in the normal app works fine.

Comment: I am affraid that you need root access for that

Comment: have you added permissions to manifest if you are testing on device API 23 or above you have to do runtime permission check